# Replace NULL column after SQL UNION

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using a UNION to combine the results of two select statements. In one statement I find the `identity` of a `sender` and in the other I find the `identity` of a `recipient`. The problem I'm running into is that my row count is always twice what it "should" be as there will always be a "blank" `sender` for the recipient results and a "blank" `recipient` for sender results. How can I restructure this to return one row for each transaction which has both `sender` and `recipient` filled in?

```
(
  SELECT s.id, s.sender_id, '' AS sender, NOW() AS sender_create_date, s.recipient_id,
    MAX(c.identity) AS recipient, MAX(c.create_date) AS recipient_create_date
  FROM db.sales s
  LEFT JOIN db.customers c ON c.participant_id = s.recipient_id
  WHERE sender_id = $1
  OR recipient_id = $1
  GROUP BY s.id
)
UNION
(
  SELECT s.id, MAX(c.identity) AS sender, MAX(c.create_date) AS sender_create_date, s.recipient_id,
    '' AS recipient, NOW() AS recipient_create_date
  FROM db.sales s
  LEFT JOIN db.customers c ON c.participant_id = s.recipient_id
  WHERE sender_id = $1
  OR recipient_id = $1
  GROUP BY s.id
)
```

Here is an example of my current results for one transaction:

```
id | sender | sender_create_date | recipient | recipient_create_date
1  |  bob   |     11/1/2016      |           |    11/22/2016
1  |        |     11/22/2016     |    jill   |    11/5/2016
```

What I am aiming for is:

```
id | sender | sender_create_date | recipient | recipient_create_date
1  |  bob   |     11/1/2016      |   jill    |    11/5/2016
```

Comment: Try describing what you want the query to actually do.

Comment: Why a union at all?  (the union is what's causing the multiple lines. Seems like 2 joins to customers is needed. once for sender, once for recipient.  (note you're likely getting 4 records and the UNION is doing a distinct eliminating 2.)

Comment: @xQbert Unfortunately `c.participant_id` is not unique. `db.customers` can contain multiple rows with the same `participant_id`. I want to grab the most recent `c.create_date` for the `participant_id`.

Comment: @xQbert Ah, you're correct. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, will post solution.

Comment: in your select result is do you see any rows which have the style you want?
does the select that give you your first result also give you the second result(the one that you're aiming for)?

Comment: From the example you have provided if one row has recipient null and another has sender null then those two are separate rows and can't be merged into one row. Union is not for merging two records into one. What you can do instead is have both recipient and sender values in one column (of resultset) and another column for type...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out what I was aiming for can be accomplished with two joins:

```
SELECT s.id, MAX(cs.identity) AS sender, MAX(cs.create_date) AS sender_create_date, MAX(cr.identity) AS recipient, MAX(cr.create_date) AS recipient_create_date
FROM db.sales s
LEFT JOIN db.customers cr ON cr.participant_id = s.recipient_id
LEFT JOIN db.customers cs ON cs.participant_id = s.sender_id
WHERE sender_id = $1
OR recipient_id = $1
GROUP BY s.id;
```